# How to select multiple relative objects of a single object at once Django ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

So I have two classes one is Book and another one is Category initially I have add the foreign key in Book which points to Category.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Book(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

And it works fine I was able to select a category from a selected book inside the admin panel

> But now I want to select books from category section so that I can select all the books which are of that single category. And for that I changed the code in the following way

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title

class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

> The upper code returns tons of errors.

Let suppose I have four books in Book table and one category in Category table. so now I want to relate all those books to that category in Category table by just opening a single category. What happening right now is that I have to open each book entry and relate to it's category. But I want a drop down menu inside a category's admin panel where I can select all the books of that category. It will be also one to many as single book relate to a single category but one category can has many books.
IS IT POSSIBLE ?

Comment: didn't click a good question's title sorry.

Comment: Everything is possible if you can program it!

Comment: If anyone found a better question title which explains this. then please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna edit multiple books from a category that belongs to it, you can keep the first piece of code and add Inlines to category from admin.py

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Book(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book



@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]
```

Comment: Oh man it works I replace admin.site.register(Book) and admin.site.register(Category) with you piece of code @admin.register(Book) and @admin.register(Category) and it works. JAADU

Comment: I play with your code and found out that when I write @admin.register(Book) just above the BookAdmin and @admin.register(Category) above CategoryAdmin then only it work.

Comment: Do you know what's the hack.